# Does JS work in popup windows?

Tags: javascript, popup

I want a popup window containing a canvas, but I'm unable to get the JS to work in the popup.

Here's a toy program that shows the problem, trying to get 'alert' to work in the popup.

```
    <html> <head>  <title> popup test </title>
    <script language="javascript">
    function popup()
{OpenWindow=window.open("","","height=250,width=250");
OpenWindow.document.write("<html><body bgcolor=pink>Hello!");
OpenWindow.document.write("<form><input type='button' value='alert' onclick='doalert()'></form> ");
OpenWindow.document.write("</body></html>");
}
    function doalert() { alert("Got in");}
    </script> </head>
    <body>
<input type="button" onclick='popup()' value="click to see new window">
    </body></html>
```

The alert button shows in the popup window, blinks when I click it, but doesn't put up the alert box.

Comment: The document you open in the new window doesn't have a `doalert()` function.

Comment: It doesn't work because the `doalert()` function is defined in the parent window, not the popup. If you must do it this way, try `window.opener.doalert`

Answer (score 1):

Define doalert in the child window:

```
<html> <head>  <title> popup test </title>
<script language="javascript">
    function popup() {
        OpenWindow=window.open("","","height=250,width=250");
        OpenWindow.document.write("<html><body bgcolor=pink>Hello!");
        OpenWindow.document.write('<script language="javascript">function doalert() { alert("Got in"); } <\/script>');
        OpenWindow.document.write("<form><input type='button' value='alert' onclick='doalert()'></form>");
        OpenWindow.document.write("</body></html>");
    }
</script> </head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick='popup()' value="click to see new window">
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "doalert()" must be initiated only when the new window get loaded. Put these kind of functions which are needed to be work in parent window and child window in a function and trigger them when each window opens are when new codes are inserted or included to a page.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. The interesting problem now is that the browser (FF) executes html commands even when they are within quotes.